# What is the best way to implement a B2B communication?

Tags: erp, edi, edifact, cxml

For my bachelor´s degree I got the task to implement a B2B communication for an ERP system developed by the company I currently work for. Because it should also be able to communicate with other software I consider using EDI messages (EDIFACT) or maybe cXML. What is the best way to approach this task.

I had the idea to translate the EDIFACT message into xml defined by one xsd describing every EDIFACT message. 
Then I would write the xml into the database or to business objects using a selfwritten mapper.
For writing EDIFACT messages I just use the same methods the other way round.
I thought using XML transformation first would be easier for the mapping and gives the opportunity using the xml for other purposes like writing other edi formats.
The other idea is to just use cXML and map it.

What is the best approach to this task?

Comment: The crucial part is the import/export (for the company). The mapping software etc is already invented, no need to invent it again. The problem is NOT using xsd or whatever you use (many options), point is how to maintain/deal with it. cXML is used by limited nr of users, chemical industry. Edifact is used by many (outside USA), but if customer says: use xxxx, you'll use xxxx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're essentially designing and implementing a public facing API for the ERP, so you need to consider security, reliability, non-repudiation, impact on business process under normal and abnormal conditions.

You'll also need to consider (ask) what sorts of information your customers will need to exchange with their partners (master data, transactional messages, financial information, etc).

I'd start by looking at the most commonly exchanged messages in the industry most representative of the ERPs users - look for message content and structure.

whether you choose to use EDIFACT, ANSI X12, cXML, XCBL, GS1XML, ebXML or something else is less important than good documentation and flexibility. it's unlikely that your choice will be exactly what any of your customers need without further transformation. you don't want to invent a new any to any transformation tool, and you probably don't even want to bundle an existing one.